# Android layout qualifier does't work

Tags: android, layout, size

Problem:When I tested my program on different size Android phones, the layout were not selected correctly.

I used `setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)` to set the layout.

In the res/ directory, I created

```
res/layout/activity_home.xml
res/layout-sw320dp/activity_home.xml
res/layout-sw480dp/activity_home.xml
res/layout-sw720dp/activity_home.xml
```

In the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
            android:largeScreens="true"  
            android:normalScreens="true" 
            android:smallScreens="false"  
            android:anyDensity="true"
 />
```

Then I tested it seperately on **320x480，480x800，720x1280** emulators. All these devices selected the layout `/res/layout-sw320dp/activity_home.xml`.

The target platform I set is 4.4.2 and the emulator's version is 4.3.3.

I have no idea why this happened..

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html
 and
/ [here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html%20and)
[here](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)

use this link and use the directory structure to support multiple screens

Hope it may help u

Comment: I think I am using the directory structure correctly, which obeys to the qualifiers' rule on the guide.